# write a program to walk through another program

Tags: java, c++, windows

Hey I want to be able to create a program that accepts inputs, writes it to another program, and run specific processes on that program.

For example:

Without this program I'm creating, I would input URLs into OutWit(scraping program). Then I would click scrapers, type in the marker before and after(marker is static since I'm pulling from the same website). Then I would right click on the URLs and add them to queries, etc. In the end it would save data for me into an excel file.

I'm hoping to write a program that just takes in the URLs and does all the repetitive OutWit stuff for me to save time. I'm literally doing the same thing over and over again, with slightly different URLs every so often. Is there a way to write a program so that I would only have to input the URLs?

Thank You!!

Comment: This question doesn't really belong on this site, but the way I'd guide you is to write the scraper program, have it output the data you need scraped each on a line, then write the next program to go through each line of the input file/text and perform the necessary operations. In Unix, the workflow would be like `java firstProgram urlListFile | java secondProgram > outputFile`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it sounds like maybe you don't have the experience to actually write said program (just a guess). If that's the case, I think you'll find it **much** easier to create a macro to do the same thing.

Try using AutoHotKey:

http://www.autohotkey.com/

You can make a basic script that will open a dialog for you to paste your URL into, then it can send any necessary keyboard and mouse interactions to your scraping program, with pauses in between if necessary.

I hope this helps.